# Button.setEnabled doesn't work in the first loop

Tags: java, for-loop, jframe, jbutton

I am working on a little game which I am coding using `JFrame`. I created a `JPanel` in which I have a board created with `JButtons`. I had to check if any letter is the same in a column/line and diagonally. So I created a method which does that for me. The problem is the first statement I put in method won't disable the button even though the program actually reaches that part of code. So I tried a few things to fix it and I just don't understand why the first loop will not disable the Button while following loops will.

```
 private void checkRepetitions()
{

    Boolean check = false;
    int i, j;
    //check in line
    i = lastI;

        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            if (tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals(tab[i][j].getText()) && lastI != j && !tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals("")) {
                confirm.setEnabled(false);
                check = true;
                break;
            } else {
                confirm.setEnabled(true);

            }
        }


    //checkin column
    j = lastJ;

        for (i=0; i<8; i++){
            if(tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals(tab[i][j].getText()) && lastI != i && !tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals("")){
                confirm.setEnabled(false);
                check = true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                confirm.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }


    //scheck diagonally
    i = 0;
    j = 0;

    if (lastJ == lastI) {
        while (i<7 && j<7) {

            if(tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals(tab[i][j].getText()) && lastI != i && !tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals("")){
                confirm.setEnabled(false);
                check = true;
                break;
            }

            else if(i<8&& j<8){
                i++;
                j++;
            }

            else{
                confirm.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    }
    //check diagonally
    i = 0;
    j = 7;
    if (lastI + lastJ == 7) {
        while (true){

            if(tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals(tab[i][j].getText()) && lastI != i && lastJ != j && !tab[lastI][lastJ].getText().equals("")){
                confirm.setEnabled(false);
                check = true;
                break;
            }
            else{
                confirm.setEnabled(true);
            }
            if (i == 7 && j == 0){
                break;
            }
            else{
                i++;
                j--;
            }


        }
    }

}
```

`lastI` and `lastJ` are variables that holds the position of the last button user clicked on and for that button I check then if there are repetitions. `confirm` button is supposed to get disabled and it does with every loop but the first `for` loop. `Boolean` is not used right now so it doesn't impact the code.

Comment: I'd be easier to debug if the code was runnable. Perhaps break the code down so it's not reliant on the UI and instead the state is carried in some kind of model which can easily be replicated

Comment: Probably because your other loops are re-enabling the suspect button again. If the condition is true in any loop then disable the button and **exit the method** from within that loop or after each of the first two loops have `if (check) { return; }`.

Comment: Consider posting [mcve]

Comment: I rewrote the whole method in the same way actually and added as @DevilsHnd said `if (check) {return;}` and now it seems to work like a charm. Thanks for all the sugestions!